# Jquery functions are not executing properly on iphone

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone

Ok, I have the code:

```
$( function() {
$('#questionSearchInput').keyup(function(){
    var list = [];
    search = $(this).val().toString();
    searchArray = search.split(" ");
    console.log(searchArray);
    $.each(grabbedItems, function(j, question){
        question.score = 0;
        console.log(question.score);
    });
    if(searchArray[0]){
        $.each(grabbedItems, function(i, question){
            lowerName = question.name.toLowerCase();
            if(lowerName.indexOf(searchArray[0]) > -1){
                question.score = question.score + 1;
                console.log(question.score);
            }
        });
    }
    if(searchArray[1]){
        $.each(grabbedItems, function(i, question){
            lowerName = question.name.toLowerCase();
            if(lowerName.indexOf(searchArray[1]) > -1){
                question.score = question.score + 1;
                console.log(question.score);
            }
        });
    }
}
    grabbedItems.sort(function(a, b){
        return b.score - a.score;
    });
    if(grabbedItems.length < 1){
        document.getElementById("noQuestionsP").style.display = "block";
    }
    clearBox("questionNamesDisplay");
    $.each(grabbedItems, function(k, question){
        if(k < 5){
            var place = document.getElementById("questionNamesDisplay");
            var item = document.createElement("a");
            item.innerHTML = question.name;
            item.href = question.link;
            item.style.display = "block";
            place.appendChild(item);
        }
    });
});
});
```

var grabbedItems is retrieved via a post request before this function executes. Console log shows it's accurate.

My problem is that the function actually works fine on my laptop in firefox, But when I run it on my iphone the function doesn't run correctly. I have no way of diagnosing what's wrong with it. But it doesn't function properly. Does anyone have any advise for a newbie on how I can diagnose what's wrong with it.

Comment: Enable web inspector on your phone and use it to debug. More info at https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/

Comment: great thanks, My Iphone is quite new so I had no idea

Comment: that doesn't actually help as I haven't got a mac